# Cant Use Copy and Paste when I have and Excel VBA Macro Running

Tags: vba, excel

Whenever I run a certain report macro in Excel I cannot use Copy and Paste elsewhere. For instance say I start up the report(depending on how many lines can take 30+ minutes) and then go work elsewhere while its running in the background it doesn't allow me to copy and paste. The only thing it does paste is whatever the Macro is currently working on and If I try to copy something it gets inserted into the next cell on the report messing that report up.

Looking for any advice or if anyone else has heard of this.

Thanks.

Comment: Does the report explicitly rely on the clipboard, by any chance?

Comment: Yes it uses 
Range("A1").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("B1").Select
ActiveSheet.paste

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you even need copy/paste?  Perhaps under the covers VBA isn't really copy/pasting, per-se, but if you only need the values, why not:

```
Range("B1").Value = Range("A1").Value
```

Bear in mind you can truly do this for ranges, not just cells

```
Range("B1:B100").Value = Range("A1:A100").Value
```

This won't copy formats and such, but you can add those as well:

```
Range("A1").NumberFormat = Range("B1").NumberFormat
```

This may not be as tidy, code-wise as what you seek with a copy/paste, but I'd encourage you to benchmark it and see which is more efficient.  Again, perhaps it's all the same under the hood; I really don't know.

Comment: Sweet Glad you Let me know, I was going to try and Loop of some sort but now that I know you can do Ranges all is Gravy!  Thanks Hambone!

Answer (score 0):

By using:

```
Range("A1").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("B1").Select
Selection.Paste
```

I was using my Active Clipboard ergo why I couldn't Copy and Paste by altering it to:

```
Range("A1?).Copy Destination:=Range("B1?)
```

It will do the same thing only not use your active clipboard and be way more efficient.